# Difference between normalized difference and standardized mean difference in cobalt?

Tags: r, causality, propensity-scores, matching, covariate-balance

In Imbens & Wooldridge ([2009, p. 19](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jel.47.1.5)), they define the **normalized difference** as:

[image: Normalized difference]

whereas the [cobalt](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/index.html)'s package **standardized mean difference** uses by default (for the ATE) "the 'pooled' standard deviation (i.e., the square root of the mean of the group variances) in calculating standardized mean differences" (https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/reference/bal.tab.html#with-binary-point-treatments).

What is the difference between using the sum of the sample variances versus using the mean of the sample variances? Which is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the "normalized difference" in the cited article is an error and the standardized mean difference as described in all other articles on assessing balance and the `cobalt` documentation is correct. The sum of two variances is not a valid way to represent the variability of the distribution of the covariates. This is likely a typo or a misunderstanding by the authors.

The authors say (p. 24)

> Imbens and Rubin (forthcoming) suggest as a rule of thumb that with a
> normalized difference exceeding one quarter, linear regression methods
> tend to be sensitive to the specification.

Take a look at the normalized difference in Imbens and Rubin (2015, Ch 15.2, p. 339):

[image]

This definition of the normalized difference is correct and consistent with that used in `cobalt`.